# How fix error, in Unity that vr SDK cardboard not supported in editor player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sdk, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

Virtual Reality SDK Cardboard is not supported in Editor Play Mode. Please Build and run on a supported target device.
Will attempt to enable Daydream instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity: VRDevice cardboard not supported in Editor Mode. Please run on target device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44774254/unity-vrdevice-cardboard-not-supported-in-editor-mode-please-run-on-target-dev)

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your application on a supported platform like **mobile**, because in the Editor play mode, the **Cardboard sdk** can't work properly.

Try to export your app and run it in mobile directly.